# Passing a structure member name to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, structure

Here is a basic code that does not work.

```
struct s_date {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
} date;

void showMonth(date.month);

int main()
{

cout << "Enter a number";
cin >> date.month;

showMonth(date.month);

return 0;
}

void showMonth(date.month) {
switch (date.month) {
    case 1:
    cout << "January";
    break;

    //...
    }
}
```

How can I pass a specific structure member name (such as date.month) to a function as shown here?

Comment: You don't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: `void showMonth(int month)`

Comment: You can do this by changing the type of month. Instead of making it int, create a new `enum class` and make `month` an instance of that class.

Comment: Before posting your question, I believe it is better to understand what the compiler say of your program. You code is not legal in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `showMonth()` function is structured wrong.  It needs to be more like this instead:

```
struct s_date {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
} date;

void showMonth(int month);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number";
    cin >> date.month;

    showMonth(date.month);

    return 0;
}

void showMonth(int month) {
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            cout << "January";
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not reflective like Java, C#, Python, Ruby, et al. languages. So you have to provide the string yourself (e.g. "date.month") but it is up to you to sync with the actual struct definition.